# Multiple language support in Conversation Action

Tags: actions-on-google

I am planning to design a google action, which will help users to learn some phrases in another language lets say "French". Here is an Example:-

“ok google, let me talk to learn french”

LearnFrench (LF): Hi! This is learn french! Would you like to practice 20 of the most important basic phrases in speaking French?”

user: “Yes”

LF: “Great! I’ll start by telling you a word in French - and you repeat after me.  Let’s start with bonjour.

user: bonjour

LF: that was good! Bonjour is the most common greeting you’ll need. Next is "bonsoir" / or let’s try that again, it didn’t quite sound like “bonjour”

user: bonsoir

LF: bonsoir is used as a in the early evening,

etc….continues through 20 or so phrases.  After going through those then there could be some type of “recall” practice.  LF would say the phrase in English and the user would say the phrase in French.  And if the user says it incorrectly then LF “learns” the phrases that the user needs to improve on.

At the end of a session LF would say something like “I think you know the basics here - good luck on your trip”.

If after that session the user came back to LF - LF would know that the user had already come before and would ask if they want to repeat the tutorial - or ask if they want to move straight to the quiz.

Is it possible to have multiple language support?

Comment: I guess the short answer is for now: Not yet.

Answer (score 0):

While Google Assistant is available in other languages, the Actions on Google platform is currently only available in U.S. English and U.K. English. We’re working to make Actions on Google available in other languages, but we don’t have a formal release date. We’ll make announcements to the community with updates as they occur.

If you are already using the invocation name, it is not possible to link it to another project/app.

Thanks,
Actions on Google Support Team